# Child div isn't appearing at all. Text within div is appearing

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to split my page into two "columns" using two divs floated next to each other. The container width is 900px, the left column should be 400px and the right column 500px.

My problem is that the text within the first div will appear (although taking up the full 900px) but the div itself shows no signs of being there, even when I apply a border or background color. The same for the right hand div.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">       
    <div id="leftpanel">
        <h1>Left Panel Title Here</h1>
        <p>Summary text goes underneath to draw attention to the
           video on the right</p>
    </div>

    <div id="rightpanel">
        <p>123 123</p>
    </div>

     <div id="content"><p>text to expand page</p>
    </div>

    <div id="columna">
    </div>

    <div id="columnb"></div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:#333;}

    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400);
    h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;}

    p{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;}

    #container{
    width: 900px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;}

     #header{
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;}

    #cssmenu {
    background: #f96e5b;
    width: auto;}

    #cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;}

    #cssmenu ul:after {
     content: ' ';
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     height: 0;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;}

     #cssmenu ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;} 

     #cssmenu.align-right ul li {
     float: right;}

     #cssmenu.align-center ul {
     text-align: center;}

     #cssmenu ul li a {
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     padding: 15px 25px;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 14px;
     position: relative;
     -webkit-transition: color .25s;
     -moz-transition: color .25s;
     -ms-transition: color .25s;
     -o-transition: color .25s;
     transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }

#leftpanel{
    width: 400px;
    float:left;
    border:solid;}

#rightpanel{
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: You have an  unclosed @media query '@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {' needs to be closed before #leftpanel.

Comment: Thank you Jim! You've saved me a real headache

Comment: as a advice try to tabulate you code...this css is small in comparisson of anothers...always tabulate your code :-D Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS style with the close media query:

```
   body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:#333;}

    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400);
    h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;}

    p{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;}

    #container{
    width: 900px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;}

     #header{
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;}

    #cssmenu {
    background: #f96e5b;
    width: auto;}

    #cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;}

    #cssmenu ul:after {
     content: ' ';
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     height: 0;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;}

     #cssmenu ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;} 

     #cssmenu.align-right ul li {
     float: right;}

     #cssmenu.align-center ul {
     text-align: center;}

     #cssmenu ul li a {
     color: #ffffff;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     padding: 15px 25px;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 700;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 14px;
     position: relative;
     -webkit-transition: color .25s;
     -moz-transition: color .25s;
     -ms-transition: color .25s;
     -o-transition: color .25s;
     transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}

#leftpanel{
    width: 400px;
    float:left;
    border:solid;}

#rightpanel{
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you have this unclosed in your css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
```

try to close that and check if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` in the left and right panel

```
 #leftpanel{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 400px;
    float:left;
    border:solid;
}

#rightpanel{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 500px;
}
```

And do not forget to close your media query.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few things here -

You need to close the media query. Thats why having the rules for left and right panel at the bottom of the CSS code is not working correctly. So close that, then move the rules up to the top of the page for a more legible code (I put them just below container, but I guess thats personal preference). Secondly the border you have around the left panel stops the two boxes sitting side by side - do that and add     float:right; 
to the rightPanel CSS. Should be all good.

Ash